# Adding a graphic to Bootstrap progress bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I'd like to make a custom Bootstrap progress-tracker like this:

[image: example]

with pure HTML/CSS. This is what I have so far

HTML:

```
<div class="progress progress-manager">   
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-done" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="14" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style: "width:14%">
        <div id="circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#circle{
    color: blue;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Which spits out the following (notice the circle doesn't extend past the progress bar):

[image: won't display circle graphic properly]

Bootstrap doesn't have a `:before` pseudo element for its progress bar, so how might I achieve a result similar to the example?

Comment: just came up with this, not sure if it will work for you: **http://jsfiddle.net/4e5dS/2/**

Comment: Tried it, but when using with bootstrap progress-bar the :after content can't extend past the progress-bar, just like in the example I showed. I tried changing the z-order and making position relative but did not change anything.

Comment: The problem is that `.progress` applies `overflow:hidden` so no child elements will ever be taller than the wrapper.  And no elements outside of `.progress` can be positioned relative to the children.  I'd take a look at [Popping Out of Hidden Overflow](http://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/)

Comment: @KyleMit your answer led me in the correct direction - I just set the  parent element's `overflow` value to `visible` and it worked. In this case, the parent element is `<div class="progress progress-manager">`. If you post your reply as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.progress` class applies `overflow: hidden` so no child elements will ever be taller than the wrapper. And no elements outside of `.progress` can be positioned relative to the children.

One way to solve this would be to remove the overflow rule on the `.progress` wrapper like this:

```css
.progress {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Then you have to manually apply the border radius to the `.progress-bar` since it is no longer confined by it's parent:

```css
.progress-bar {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Then you can add a circle at the end of the `.progress-bar` by adding an element with the `:after` pseudo class and adding a border radius equal to half of the element's width/height.

```css
.progress-bar:after {
    content:"";
    background-color: darkgreen;
    
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px; 
       -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
            border-radius: 15px;
    
    float: right;
}
```

### [Demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/wD374/)

Which will look like this:

[image: screenshot]

> **Warning**: `overflow:hidden` was there for a reason.  I'm not sure why, but this might have unintended consequences.